# Checking for ^ character in java string

Tags: java, regex

I want to check a string to see if it contains the ^ symbol, and if it does display a message to the user.

Thanks

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("StringGoesHere");
boolean b = m.find();

if (b){
   System.out.println("bad");
} else {
   System.out.println("fine");
}
```

Comment: ... Add it to the pattern, and escape it with a `\`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

a regex might be an overkill, just use [`String.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

If you are eager to use a regex, use `"\\^"`: `\\` will provide a single `\`, which is breaking the special meaning of the `^` char.

Comment: I think you'll find that String.indexOf(char) is quite a bit faster than String.contains(CharSequence) when searching for a single character.

Comment: @TheRealBaumann: Micro-Optimization. I believe most compilers will treat the two statements the same [assuming the string is a literal with a constant character]. `contains()` is more readable. Remember: optimizations are for compilers, and readability is for programmers.

Comment: Java's implementation of contains actually just calls String.indexOf( CharSequence.toString() ), so you're dealing with a cast from String to CharSequence back to String for the most common uses.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just

```
String str = "StringGoesHere";
if( str.indexOf('^') != -1 )
{
    System.out.println( "bad" );
}
else
{
    System.out.println("fine");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\^");
```

Comment: That will actually match the *beginning of a string*.

Comment: Isn't that "start of line" if not escaped?

Comment: (edited since, so these comments no longer apply. The expression was `"^"` then)

Comment: Yes, I added the escape. I thought you had to use the multi-line option to turn on ^ recognition, but it is useful for `find()`. (`match()` has to match a complete string anyway, so `^` is unnecessary there.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the simplest answer would be: don't use an regexp, just search for the character itself.

The longer answer is: see the details of the regular expression syntax on *escaping*.

In charcter classes, `^` is only special if it is the *first* symbol. So `[a-z^]` will match any of `a-z` *or* `^`, while `[^a-z]` matches everything except `a-z` (since `^` as first character is negation).

Outside of a character class, `^` matches the beginning of the line, unless you escape it with `\`. And for Java inline strings, you need to write that as `"\\^"`.